# Via Pyinstaller compiled .exe keeps shuttingdown maybe by sklearn-imports

Tags: python, scikit-learn, conda, pyinstaller

i am trying to make a .exe with pyinstaller (6.0.0)
I made a test.py that has nothing but a clickable exit-button.
the .exe runs just fine as long as i exclude the sklearn-imports which are the following:

```
from sklearnex import patch_sklearn
patch_sklearn()
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift
```

Unfortunately they are crutial for the target-script that need be compiled

i made a hook-file:
`hiddenimports = ['sklearn']`
*taken by another post*

i still get warnings while compiling:

```
837915 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'ze_loader.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\Student\\anaconda3\\envs\\occ\\Library\\bin\\omptarget.rtl.level0.dll'.
837916 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'libfabric.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\Student\\anaconda3\\envs\\occ\\Library\\bin\\impi.dll'.
```

the script in my anaconda environment runs just finde, but not as an .exe
Its python 3.10.5

Please let me know if i need to provide more information.
i'm pretty new in developments